# Using computed with dynamic objects in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties, vuelidate

**Hey gang**

Since I'm kind of new to Vue JS, I've managed to almost complete a simple staged form project, I'm having trouble with a dynamic object

**Assuming that this is the last stage of the form:**

```
<template v-if="currentStage === 3">
  <h2>Step 3 - Additional Params</h2>
  <h3>Please fill all the parameters needed</h3>
  <div v-for="(param, key, index) in params" :key="key">
    <label class="inputLabel" :for="key">Please fill in {{ key }} param</label> <span class="redStar">*</span>
    <input v-model="params[key]" :id="key">
    <span v-if="submitted && $v.params[key] && !$v.params[key].required" class="invalid-feedback">It's a required field, please fill it</span>
    <!--        <span v-if="v$.params[key].$errors[0]" class="invalid-feedback"> {{ v$.params[key].$errors[0].$message }} </span>-->
  </div>
  <button @click="updateStage(0)">Previous</button>
  <button @click="handleLastSubmit">Create</button>
</template>
```

**Inside Data() I created an empty object destined to be fulfilled based on user input from certain field in the form, as suggested in the comment below:**

```
 params() {
      if (this.jsonS.hasOwnProperty(this.tDetails.platform)) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.jsonS[this.tDetails.platform])) {
          this.params[key] = value;
        }
      }
      return this.params;
    },
```

**I tried to add { required } based on vue forums suggestions like this(inside computed):**

```
addRequiredValidation() {
      //Here I need somehow to add validations to params Object.
      for (const key in this.integrationParams) {
          this.$options.validations().integrationParams[key].required = required
         }
      }
```

**And implement it in the validations as follows:**

```
validations() {
  return {
    integrationParams: this.addRequiredValidation,
    trafficDetails: {
      brand: {required, minLength: minLength(3)},
      platform: {required, minLength: minLength(3)},
      whitelabel: {required, minLength: minLength(3)},
      country: {required, minLength: minLength(2)},
      campaignName: {required, minLength: minLength(2)}
    }
  }
},
```

Ending up getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at Function.keys ()

Answer (score 0):

You could use another computed field to get your params.

```
computed: {
  params() {
      const params = {};
      if (this.jsonS.hasOwnProperty(this.tDetails.platform)) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.jsonS[this.tDetails.platform])) {
          params[key] = value;
        }
      }
      return params;
    }
}
```

The params should be recalculated whenever `this.tDetails.platform` changes (i.e., a user inputs another platform) and your addRequired property should update correctly.

Comment: When I use my "appendFields" function I want the params object to be fulfilled only when stage 2 of the form is completed, right after that I need to add validations, that's what I couldn't do because I don't know which keys will be in the object

Comment: I just need to be able to add "Required" validations to the dynamic object, how can I do that ?

Comment: So a user makes some input in "Stage-2" of your component and then "Stage-3" is unlocked and at that point you want to create your validation params?
Can you hook into the case, that stage-2 was successfully completed and update your params at that point? Any computed property using those params should then be updated accordingly.

Comment: If user inputed a "this.tDetails.platform" that exist, the stage3 of the form will render accordingly with the same keys that "this.tDetails.platform" has in the JSon object, But I couldn't figure out how to create a successful validations to it.

Comment: Any other suggestions bro?

Comment: What exactly are you using for validation? I'll set up a minimal example to try to emulate your case.

Comment: Hey I'm using vuelidate if that's what your asking

Comment: If you wish and could I would like to go to a live chat with u

Comment: Ok so I read it again, you basically saying that I should move my "appendfields" from method to a computed property and only by then the addRequired should work?

Comment: Sorry, been quite busy, i'll try to set up an example tonight and will msg you back. 
But yeah that's basically what I was suggesting. Did you try that?

Comment: I did, but I didn't managed to success unfortunately. 
I will edit the code to the one I have right now

Comment: We can go on a live chat if u wish